# Como criar labels em um vetor binário sem que ele se torne categórico?

Tags: r

Tenho uma variável binária em um `dataframe`, quero atribuir o `label` "não" para o valor 0 e "sim" para o valor 1 sem que o vetor se torne categórico (caso isso ocorra, não consigo usar o a função `svymean()` ).

Alguém sabe se isso é possível?

Comment: Porque não usar o `svytable()` e depois o `prop.table()` para obter o percentual?

Comment: @Rcoster, obter o percentual não é um problema, eu estava mesmo curioso se essa forma de usar label era possível. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é possível.

O que você pode fazer é deixar o R transformar em fator, e quando for usar a `svymean` fazer assim:

```
x <- c("sim", "sim", "não", "não")
svymean(x = as.numeric(x == "sim"), design = ?)
```

Veja que usar `as.numeric(x == "sim")` solta um vetor de zeros e uns:

```
[1] 1 1 0 0
```